# Oracle SQL Recycle Bin issues

Tags: oracle

1. Does the Oracle SQL Recycle Bin impact the performance?
2. For how many days Oracle Recycle bin keeps the data after deleting tables (retention period)?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables011.htm#ADMIN11679) says:

> ### What Is the Recycle Bin?
>
> The recycle bin is actually a data dictionary table containing
>   information about dropped objects. Dropped tables and any associated
>   objects such as indexes, constraints, nested tables, and the likes are
>   not removed and still occupy space. They continue to count against
>   user space quotas, until specifically purged from the recycle bin or
>   the unlikely situation where they must be purged by the database
>   because of tablespace space constraints.

I'm not aware of any performance impact.